# cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails mysql Error Number: 1452

Tags: php, mysql, sql

the berita_ukm table

```
CREATE TABLE `berita_ukm` (
  `id_berita` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `id_admin` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  `judul_berita` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,

  `content` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,

  `tanggal` date DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id_berita`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_admin`) REFERENCES `admin` (`id_admin`)
)
```

admin table

```
CREATE TABLE `berita_ukm` (
  `id_admin` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `name` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id_admin`),
)
```

and i found error like this

```
Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`tugas_akhir`.`berita_ukm`, CONSTRAINT `berita_ukm_ibfk_1`
FOREIGN KEY (`id_admin`) REFERENCES `admin` (`id_admin`))

INSERT INTO `berita_ukm` 
(`id_berita`, `tanggal`, `judul_berita`, `content`) 
VALUES ('34', '3/25/2014', 'putri', 'nfdn')
```

please help me what to do. thank you

Comment: Your code works? See [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5b0c/1).

Comment: Notice that I changed the format of the date in your insert statement. Your formatting was not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you misplaced the col names in your insert("id_berita" in place of "id_admin" ), since col "id_berita" is auto increment, you don't need to provide value for that col during insert.

```
INSERT INTO `berita_ukm` 
(`id_admin`, `tanggal`, `judul_berita`, `content`) 
VALUES ('34', '3/25/2014', 'putri', 'nfdn')
```

Comment: The `id_admin` column does not need a value, since it may contain `NULL` values and these comply with the foreign key constraint. See [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5b0c/1).